# When or How, should i use Git in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, wordpress-theming, bitbucket

Hi People I'm new to git, i just want to have an answer or a clarification regarding, how does git works with WordPress.

At the moment i install git in my wordpress, base on my understanding git is version control and it tracks all changes to the website? but unfortunately, I tried to make a test in wordpress,
1st -

1. I installed and activate plugins and I can track it through in my
   sourcetree,
2. I created 5 published pages but I can't see changes in my
   sourcetree, does git tracks created pages or posts in wordpress? or
   are there any ways to track pages and posts in wordpress using GIT?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress content (pages, posts) are stored inside database and git is not meant to track database changes. It is generally used to track coding (file) changes. Check official [guide](https://guides.github.com/introduction/git-handbook/), it will clarify git concept as well include some usage examples.

Although, there is a way to track db changes using GIT but that's way complex and have some setup requirements so you can simply take it as, "**No, you can't track pages using GIT**".

Comment: if there's a way to track DB changes in git ? so it is also possible to track pages or post created?

Comment: @CarlDaveTampoy as I mentioned above, meeting core requirement is difficult and it's complex to setup. Even if you do that it still won't be easy to trace down pages or posts changes and reverting would also be very painful process. So, I will repeat one more time, "GIT is not meant to track db changes". And why don't you make use of wordpress [revision](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/) feature to track pages and posts changes? If you are so much concerned about db changes then use some activity tracker plugin or even better option would be to use some database backup service.